# bflabel undefined

Tags: errors, lyx, classicthesis

After updating LaTeX (MacTex) with Tex Live Utility the other day I've had trouble compiling using `\bflabel`:

```
! LaTeX Error: \bflabel undefined.
```

The document I'm trying to compile is a modified version of the ClassicThesis port to Lyx, but i suspect the problem is with LaTeX and not Lyx, since the problem appeared right after i ran a batch update with Tex Live Utility.

Does anyone know how I could fix this? Is `\bflabel` part of the "standard package"? I can't find any info on `\bflabel` anywhere..

Comment: `\bflabel` is not in any "standard" package i know about.  did this work before you updated your tex system?  if so, it was defined in one of the packages that were replaced in your update.

Comment: Seems to be part of the `acronym` package, e.g. 2012/10/29, but is no longer present in the latest version.  How are you using that package?

Comment: The statement that causes the crash is
\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1}\hfill}. The file compiled just fine before the update

Comment: If you just want to continue using the command, change `\renewcommand` to `\newcommand` and it should be fine. But if you are relying on that formatting to interface with `acronym`, you'll need to update your code to reflect the new configuration macros.

Answer (score 10):

`\bflabel` is not being used in the newest implementation of `acronym.sty`, they introduced `\aclabelfont` and a few others to deal with formatting. No backward compatibility.