# Fixing a class file

Tags: macros, errors, document-classes, acronyms

This may be a problem with too narrow an audience for this forum, but I'm rather stuck at the moment.  I'm attempting to build my dissertation document.  My school's style guide is decidedly Word-centric, but I do have a LaTex class that was built by students some years ago that implements it.  Unfortunately they are no longer around to maintain it...

I successfully used this class file a couple of years ago to build my prospectus, but now even my old prospectus files throw an error.  I believe the problem has to do with a change to the acronym package.

The error that I get is

> LaTeX Error: \bflabel undefined

\bflabel appears twice in the class file, both times in this block

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \if@AFITdraft\singlespace\else\afit@doublespace\fi
  % adjust the acronym package's list format to conform to the AFIT style guide
  \@ifpackageloaded{acronym}{%
    \newcommand\afit@acronymwidth{Acronym}
    \renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1\hfill}}%
    \newlength\afit@acronymlabelsep
    \settowidth\afit@acronymlabelsep{\qquad}%
    \renewenvironment{AC@deflist}[1]{%
      \ifAC@nolist\else
        \newwrite\aftfile
        \immediate\openout\aftfile=\jobname.aft%
        \immediate\write\aftfile{\string\renewcommand\string\afit@acronymwidth{#1}}%
        \immediate\closeout\aftfile
        \raggedright\begin{list}{}{%
          \singlespace
          \setlength{\topsep}{\afit@fracskip}%
          \setlength{\itemsep}{\afit@fracskip}%
          \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
          \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
          \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
          \settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}%
          \setlength{\labelsep}{\afit@acronymlabelsep}%
          \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
          \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
          \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\bflabel}%
        }%
      \fi%
    }{%
      \ifAC@nolist\else
        \end{list}%
      \fi
    }%
    \newcommand\listofacronyms[1]{%
      \IfFileExists{\jobname.aft}{\makeatletter\input{\jobname.aft}\makeatother}{}%
      \newlength\afit@acronymleftmargin
      \settowidth\afit@acronymleftmargin{\afit@acronymwidth}%
      \addtolength\afit@acronymleftmargin{\afit@acronymlabelsep}%
      \addlistof{Acronyms}{\makebox[\afit@acronymleftmargin][l]{Acronym}Definition}{#1}%
    }
  }{}%
}
```

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207833/bflabel-undefined) on this site that provides an explanation for what's happening:

> \bflabel is not being used in the newest implementation of acronym.sty, they introduced \aclabelfont and a few others to deal with formatting. No backward compatibility.

But that doesn't really help me in terms of fixing the problem.  So at this point, I'm not sure how to proceed.  Given what happens with bflabel in the class file, is there an easy "fix"?  I have no experience at all working with class files...any ideas at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem with another .cls file. In Overleaf, this class works fine with TeXLive 2022, but when I choose TeXLive 2023, it doesn't work. I have been trying to build it on a local machine, but without success at the moment. I look into the class file to simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider producing a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which really narrows down the problem.

Basically, this error is LaTeX's way of telling you that, though you're asking it to `\renewcommand` the control sequence `\bflabel`, there is no control sequence `\bflabel` for it to renew.  Simple deleting the `re` will eliminate the error, though I don't know if the result is what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\newcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1\hfill}}%
\begin{document}
Here I am \bflabel{what} now
\end{document}
```

So if you copy your `cls` file to your working directory, and remove that `re` from `\renewcommand`, you shouldn't throw this particular error.  (Probably; without the `cls` file to inspect, there could be some other strange things going on.  But it's worth a shot.)

Comment: I wasn't even sure where to start in trying to construct an MWE.  The class file is over 1,000 lines long, and knowing nothing about class files I wouldn't know what to include and what to leave out.  My dissertation file doesn't even use any of the functionality provided by the acronym package (yet).  Right now I'm just trying to get a start on reformatting the journal articles I've written to comply with the style guide....

Comment: For now I think I'm just going to have to not load the acronym package.  I'll continue to research and see if I can figure out what `bflabel` used to do, and what new commands have been introduced to accomplish the same goals.  Then I can try to figure out what `\newcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1\hfill}}%` accomplished and port to the new commands...any pointers are greatly appreciated.  Particularly if anyone has the documentation that accompanied a version of the acronym package that still had `\bflabel`