# Doesn't the acronym package define \aclabelfont?

Tags: errors, acronyms

I am trying to build this minimalistic document which only imports the `acronym` package and attempts to redefine the `\aclabelfont` macro:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acronym}
\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{\acsfont{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

But all I get is this:

```
$ pdflatex report.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./report.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 7 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acronym/acronym.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/suffix.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex)))

! LaTeX Error: \aclabelfont undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}
                                [1]{\textbf{\textsf{\acsfont{#1}}}}
? 
(./report.aux) (./report.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on report.log.
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: You're example works for me (TeXLive 2015 on Linux). Perhaps `\aclabelfont` is a 'recent' addition

Comment: You ned to do an update.

Comment: [bflabel undefined](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208991)

Comment: That reminds me that I never wanted to use Ubuntu's TexLive packages ever again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 packages the slightly outdated TexLive 2013 these days. The `acronym` package has changed a little since then. One of these changes was the introduction of the macro `\aclabelfont`, which was previously not available.

The problem can be resolved by removing the existing TexLive installation and installing the most recent version manually.

For reference:

- http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html
- http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html